# Coordinates of ARImageAnchor transform matrix are way too different from the ARPlaneAnchor ones

Tags: ios, swift, augmented-reality, arkit

I am doing this simple thing:

1. Vertical plane detection
2. Image recognition on a vertical plane

The image is hanged on the detected plane (on my wall). In both case I implement the `renderer:didAddNode:forAnchor:` function from [`ARSCNViewDelegate`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/arkit/arscnviewdelegate/2865794-renderer?language=objc). I stand at the place for the vertical plane detection and the image recognition.

```
func renderer(_ renderer: SCNSceneRenderer, didAdd node: SCNNode, for anchor: ARAnchor) {
    guard let shipScene = SCNScene(named: "ship.scn"), let shipNode = shipScene.rootNode.childNode(withName: "ship", recursively: false) else { return }
    shipNode.position = SCNVector3(anchor.transform.columns.3.x, anchor.transform.columns.3.y, anchor.transform.columns.3.z)
    sceneView.scene.rootNode.addChildNode(shipNode)
    print(anchor.transform)
}
```

In the case of a vertical plane detection the `anchor` will be an `ARPlaneAnchor`. In the case of an image recognition the `anchor` will be an `ARImageAnchor`.

Why are the transform matrices of those two anchors so different? I'm printing the `anchor.transform` and I get those results:

1.

```
simd_float4x4([
    [0.941312,  0.0,        -0.337538,  0.0)],
    [0.336284,  -0.0861278, 0.937814,   0.0)],
    [-0.0290714,-0.996284,  -0.0810731, 0.0)],
    [0.191099,  0.172432,   -1.14543,   1.0)]
])
```

2.

```
simd_float4x4([
    [0.361231,  0.10894,    0.926093,   0.0)],
    [-0.919883, -0.121052,  0.373049,   0.0)],
    [0.152743,  -0.986651,  0.0564843,  0.0)],
    [75.4418,   10.9618,    -14.3788,   1.0)]
])
```

So if I want to place a 3D object on the detected vertical plane I can simply use `[x = 0.191099, y = 0.172432, z = -1.14543]` as coordinates to set the position of my node (`myNode`), and then add this node to the scene with `sceneView.scene.rootNode.addChildNode(myNode)` but if I want to place a 3D object at the detected image's anchor, I cannot use `[x = 75.4418, y = 10.9618, z = -14.3788]`.

What should I do to place a 3D object on the detected image's anchor? I really don't understand the transform matrix of the ARImageAnchor.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is an example for you in which I use the `func renderer(_ renderer: SCNSceneRenderer, didAdd node: SCNNode, for anchor: ARAnchor)` method:

```
func renderer(_ renderer: SCNSceneRenderer, didAdd node: SCNNode, for anchor: ARAnchor) {

    //1. If Out Target Image Has Been Detected Than Get The Corresponding Anchor
    guard let currentImageAnchor = anchor as? ARImageAnchor else { return }

    let x = currentImageAnchor.transform
    print(x.columns.3.x, x.columns.3.y , x.columns.3.z)

    //2. Get The Targets Name
    let name = currentImageAnchor.referenceImage.name!

    //3. Get The Targets Width & Height In Meters
    let width = currentImageAnchor.referenceImage.physicalSize.width
    let height = currentImageAnchor.referenceImage.physicalSize.height

    print("""
    Image Name = \(name)
    Image Width = \(width)
    Image Height = \(height)
    """)

    //4. Create A Plane Geometry To Cover The ARImageAnchor
    let planeNode = SCNNode()
    let planeGeometry = SCNPlane(width: width, height: height)
    planeGeometry.firstMaterial?.diffuse.contents = UIColor.white
    planeNode.opacity = 0.25
    planeNode.geometry = planeGeometry

    //5. Rotate The PlaneNode To Horizontal
    planeNode.eulerAngles.x = -.pi/2

    //The Node Is Centered In The Anchor (0,0,0)
    node.addChildNode(planeNode)


    //6. Create AN SCNBox
    let boxNode = SCNNode()
    let boxGeometry = SCNBox(width: 0.1, height: 0.1, length: 0.1, chamferRadius: 0)

    //7. Create A Different Colour For Each Face
    let faceColours = [UIColor.red, UIColor.green, UIColor.blue, UIColor.cyan, UIColor.yellow, UIColor.gray]
    var faceMaterials = [SCNMaterial]()

    //8. Apply It To Each Face
    for face in 0 ..< 5{
        let material = SCNMaterial()
        material.diffuse.contents = faceColours[face]
        faceMaterials.append(material)
    }
    boxGeometry.materials = faceMaterials
    boxNode.geometry = boxGeometry

    //9. Set The Boxes Position To Be Placed On The Plane (node.x + box.height)
    boxNode.position = SCNVector3(0 , 0.05, 0)

    //10. Add The Box To The Node
    node.addChildNode(boxNode)


}
```

From my understanding (I could of course by wrong) you would know that your placement area is the width and height of the `referenceImage.physicalSize` which is expressed in Metres:

```
let width = currentImageAnchor.referenceImage.physicalSize.width
let height = currentImageAnchor.referenceImage.physicalSize.height
```

As such you would need to scale your content (if needed to fit) within these boundaries assuming you wanted it to appear to overlay the image.

Comment: This part of your answered did everything: _".. which is expressed in Metres"_. I actually set the image size in meters instead of centimetres, which is why my matrix was so big. The image was detected as being 14 meters heigh (and not 14cm), and therefore very far away. Thank you!